# Limit lines and characters per line in textarea (Javascript, jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I need is to be able to limit the number of lines in a textarea. And to limit the number of characters in each line (force adding a newline when maximum number of characters has been added.

I am not interested in the "rows" and "cols" attributes. They do not work.

Also, I would like to have it working even if the user cuts or pastes something, or if he returns to a line and modifies it.

Comment: I don't have anything saved but I tried a lot of answers from similar requests here on Stack Overflow. None of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is an overly complex way of doing it but you can loop through the textarea and add a newline every X characters. This solution won't allow users to insert their own line breaks (it strips off any existing line breaks) .

```
<textarea onkeyup="formatTextArea(this)"></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function formatTextArea(myArea)
    {
        //strip off any line breaks first
        var str = myArea.value.replace(/\n|\r/g, "");
        var result = '';
        var i = 0
        var formattedText = '';
        //number of lines needed
        var limit = 5
        // number of characters
        var limitPerLine = 20;

        // loop through the text, adding a new line every limitPerLine characters
        // stop after limit lines
        while (str.length > 0 && i < limit) 
        {
            i++;
            formattedText += str.substring(0, limitPerLine);
            str = str.substring(limitPerLine);

            //only add a new line if we're not at the end of the content
            if(str.length > 0 && i < limit)
            {
                formattedText += '\n';
            }
        }   
        myArea.value = formattedText;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It's not really fit for what I'm trying to do because I need the user to be able to add line breaks.